# Elegant vectorized version of CHANGEM (substitute values) - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

In Matlab 2012b, there is a `changem` function that allows you to substitute elements of a matrix with other values specified by a set of keys:
[Substitute values in data array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html;jsessionid=7bc502fa8e3b3db2dde50adb52bc)

Is there an elegant/vectorized way to do the same if I don't have the Mapping toolbox?

Comment: Did you see [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/264957)?

Comment: Implemented a vectorized way to solve this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28263828/3293881)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use `ismember`:

```
A       = magic(3);
oldCode = [ 8  9];
newCode = [12 13];

[a,b] = ismember(A,oldCode);

A(a) = newCode(b(a));
```

I don't know `changem`, and I suspect the above will not fully cover its functionality (why else would TMW have introduced `changem`?), but well, it does what you asked :)

Answer (score 6):

**Vectorized implementation of `CHANGEM` with `bsxfun`, `max`**

Sometime back, I was made to write a *customized* **vectorized** version of [**`changem`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html) implemented with [**`bsxfun`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [**`max`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) as part of a much bigger problem. The referenced solution could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256925/3293881). Then, following few links I saw this post and thought it could be posted here as a solution for an easy find among future readers as also because this problem exclusively asks for an *efficient and vectorized* version of `changem`. So, here's the function code -

```
%// CHANGEM_VECTORIZED  Vectorized version of CHANGEM with MAX, BSXFUN
function B  = changem_vectorized(A,newval,oldval)

B = A;
[valid,id] = max(bsxfun(@eq,A(:),oldval(:).'),[],2); %//'
B(valid) = newval(id(valid));

return;
```

The syntax used in the custom version follows the same syntax as in `changem.m` -

```
function B = changem(A, newval, oldval)
%CHANGEM  Substitute values in data array ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you need a FOR loop.  But it's pretty straightforward:

```
function xNew = myChangeM(x,oldCode,newCode)
% xNew = myChangeM(x,oldCode,newCode)
%
%   x is a matrix of vaues
%    oldCode and newCode specify the values to replace and with what
% e.g., 
%   x = round(randn(10));
%   oldCode = [-1 -2]; 
%   newCode = [nan, 10]; %replace -1 with nan, -2 by 10
% xNew = myChangeM(x,oldCode,newCode)

xNew = x;
for repInd = 1:numel(oldCode)
    xNew(x == oldCode(repInd)) = newCode(repInd); 
end
```

Comment: See Rody's better answer above with ismember