# How to replace multiple elements from a vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, replace, element

e.g

I have a vector:

```
a=[4 4 15 15 9 9 7 7];
```

how do I efficiently replace all 4s into 1s, all 15s into 2s, 9s into 3s and 7s into 4s? instead of coding repeatly:

```
a(a==4)=1; a(a==15)=2; a(a==9)=3; a(a==7)=4; ....
```

in the case I have too many number to be replaced?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dan this is nice feature of `unique` - starting from which version is this option available. I'm stuck to 2011b an there 'stable' is an "Unrecognized option" (which made me undo the sorting on my own from time to time...).

Comment: @sebastian I'm not sure when it was introduced

Comment: @sebastian I added it to your answer, for completeness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want an "abitrary" replacement, where there's no direct relation between original and replaced value, you could use `ismember`:

```
>> map = [4 1; 15 2; 9 3; 7 4];
>> [~, loc] = ismember(a, map(:,1));
>> a(:) = map(loc,2)

a =

     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4
```

Depending on what your larger context is, you might want to check `unique`, as it seems your doing something similar. In this case for example:

```
>> [~,~,a2] = unique(a, 'stable')

a2 =

     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4
```

Which works for your example and doesn't require you to construct a map as it makes it's own based on order of appearance.

Or if your version of Matlab predates the `'stable'` property of unique` then

```
>> [~,~,a2] = unique(a)

a2 =

     1     1     4     4     3     3     2     2
```

Which is similar to your replacement, though these numbers refer to the index of each element in the **sorted** list of distinct elements in `a`, while your example seems to use  the unsorted index - though this might just be an arbitrary choice for your example.

Comment: I see that `[~,~,a] = unique(a,'stable')` suggested by @Dan is the best solution. But I don't see how your first idea would answer the question? He still needs assign a "counter" to every number, like he did before? So not such a big difference to that OP's idea. I personally would remove it... apart from that, great idea!

Comment: @thewaywewalk the OP did not define the problem such that we know the "`unique`" solution is correct. It probably is, but maybe the mapping really does need to be arbitrary. The first part of this solution answers the more general case. It is easier to read / maintain than the OPs idea.

Comment: +1. But note that some values of `loc` might be zero (if that value of `a` is not in the map). So you would need to remove them with `loc = loc(logical(loc))` before attempting to do `a(:) = map(loc,2)`

Comment: @thewaywewalk I agree with Dan. My first solution is basically a vectorized version of the OP's example, not assuming some "logical" relation between original and replacement-value. However `ismember` should at least be somewhat faster when the replacement-map becomes larger. The question in total smells like a XYProblem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377

Answer (score 3):

There is a MATLAB built-in [`changem (Substitute values in data array)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html) in [`Mapping Toolbox`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/index.html) for exactly this purpose -

```
changem(input_arr,newvals,oldvals)
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
     4     4    15    15     9     9     7     7
>> oldvals = [4,15,9,7];
>> newvals = [1, 2,3,4];
>> changem(a,newvals,oldvals)
ans =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4
```

---

If you don't have access to the `Mapping Toolbox` or if you are looking for a vectorized solution, I would like to suggest [`Vectorized implementation of CHANGEM with bsxfun, max`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28263828/3293881).